# PostgreSQL: select data by array of keys jsonb

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Let's talk about functions in PostgresSQL.
I would like to select all rows that contain the corresponding key in jsonb.

This would be best explained with an example that works:

```
SELECT x, y, z#>'{"aaa","bbb","ccc"}' as value
FROM "foo"
WHERE "x" = '1' AND "y" = '2'
```

This will return the correct result for me.
Now I would like to return all rows, but if I had 2 jsonb key.

```
SELECT x, y, z->('[{"aaa","bbb","ccc"},{"ddd","eee","fff"}]') as value
FROM "foo"
WHERE "x" = '1' AND "y" = '2'
```

This query returns me one result, but the value column is null.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with you with your issues, but there are certain expectations. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. Then post sample data and table definitions (ddl), as text - **no images**. Even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14). Also, post the current results and expected results, also as formatted test.